# LyX child document that contains a knitr Sexpr{} cannot find cached value

Tags: r, caching, parent-child, knitr, lyx

Lyx file F

```
knitr chunk caches a value for x
then text A contains several Sexpr{} calls, including Sexpr{x}
```

Compiling F to pdf works fine

Now I move text A into a separate LyX file C, make C a child file with F the master file

Rewrite F -- should produce "text A" twice

```
knitr chunk caches a value for x
text A 
\include(C)
```

Every thing works fine, compilation produces "text A" twice, EXCEPT `\Sexpr{x}` in the included portion cannot find the cached value.  I've reviewed knitr and knitr/LyX documentation and  numerous help sites, but cannot figure out how caching works (or fails to work) in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a problem of cache, but a problem of LyX, or a feature that has not been implemented. At the moment, the LyX child documents are treated as *independent* files, meaning that they are compiled in separate R sessions, so variables cannot be shared across documents. You may file a [feature request](http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome) to LyX developers. The key point is, when a LyX contains the `knitr` or `Sweave` module and is included as a child document of another document, it should not be compiled separately (hand this job over to `knitr` or `Sweave`).

Anyway, personally I do not find this a big problem -- I always put everything in one LyX document.

Comment: Thanks.  Very clear, and along the lines of what I expected.  There are a number of obvious workarounds, but it would be nice in a large knitr-lyx document with many R graphics to limit test compilations to one section.  Thanks for the prompt response.